# Python library for tick-based backtesting on cryptos

Tags: programming, backtesting, algorithmic-trading

I saw and reviewed many python backtesting libraries - pyalgotrade, zipline, catalyst, backtrader, etc.

It seems that none of the provide a straightforward way to perform "Tick-based or Multi-timeframe backtesting on CRYPTO".

- pyalgotrade seems to be only close-based.
- zipline is for stocks.
- catalyst (a fork of zipline) can simulate ticks with 1min closes, but their data provider for data ingestion is down.
- backtrader seems to be only close-based.

**What I want to achieve**

I want to perform backtests such that:

1. Indicators being calculated with daily timeframe data.
2. Main loop progress with tick-based data or at least like zipline (with closes of a shorter timeframe, like 1min).

And I need feature two for the following:

- being able to simulate stop-losses, i.e. within candle body or shadows - not only in candle close.
- being able to backtest intra-bar strategies, so it could simulate entry and exits within body of a single bar.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're going to do it properly, you should really really build your own backtesting platform. You probably have a bunch of custom ideas that aren't going to be backtest-able in a preexisting platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[backtrader's Data Replay feature](https://www.backtrader.com/docu/data-replay/data-replay/), does exactly what I was looking for. So, all you need to do is the following:

1. Create a CSV data file with 1min timeframe.
2. Load the data into a CSV data feed of backtrader.
3. Pass the data feed to cerebro (backtrader's engine) with `replaydata` utility.
4. Finally, add a strategy and other steps.

A code example to use `replaydata` is like the following:

```
cerebro.replaydata(minuteDataFeed,
                   timeframe=TimeFrame.Days,
                   compression=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using **ccxt**? This library is available on GitHub and offers *most* of what you’re looking for. It offers minutely candle data from several dozen exchanges as well as a backtesting framework which implements indicators really well. I’m not sure if they offer intra-candle strategies but their features support what you’re looking for otherwise.

Comment: Didn't know that ccxt is able to backtest. Will check it and respond here later. Thanks.

Comment: Has this library answered the question? If so please feel free to accept the answer but if not, let us know what the shortcomings of it were.

Comment: As I guessed before, ccxt does not offer ANY of what I'm looking for - It's just an exchange integration library, however a good one, maybe the best.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for it also, and I don't think anything is able to do that.
I personally re-built some backtrading program, and I think it's pretty straightforward to do especially with Pandas' ability to resample data **by time** and build candles from it.  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html

You have 2 set of data:

- The ticks/trades, over which you look in real time to compute your balance, stop loss, take profit etc. Could be 1 minute candles also (and you use the "close" data as the tick, or could be live ticks).
- The candles on which you build your indicators etc, that you can also build on-the-go as you loop over your ticks-trades. Personally, I pre-build the candles with pandas so I can "verify" that the live-built data from the trades matches exactly. And I also use the pre-computed candles to know at which time I should recompute the indicators (because when you loop over all the ticks/trades, you won't recompute the indicators every time, you have to wait for the candle to be completely built)

As for getting the data... You can get pretty good 1 minute candles (200 days) from Binance, or full trade history from Kraken from the API. Those are free and easy to get, maybe there are other ones.